# How create complex Fluent Interface in java?

Tags: java, fluent, chain

I know how design simple fluent interface class but

I want to know How write something like this (some methods access to specific methods not all)

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass()
              .A()
                 .A1() 
                 .A2()
                    .A01()                        
                    .A02()
              .B()
                 .B1()
              .C()
                 .C1() 
                    .C01()                        
                    .C02()
```

- MyClass() can **only** access to A(), B(), C()
- A()       can **only** access to A1(), A2()
- A2()      can **only** access to A01(), A02()
- B()       can **only** access to B1()
- C()       can **only** access to C1()
- C1()      can **only** access to C01(), C02()

How can I design class with fluent interface and restrict access in java?

Comment: You're calling `.B()` on the result of `.A02()`, even though your indentation tries to avoid it.  How do you plan to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you create a core class, and write a lot of interfaces, then pass it to the user as an initial interface through some entry point:

```
public class EntryPoint {
    MyClass myClass() {
        return new Implementation();
    }
}

// not visible to the user
class Implementation implements MyClass, A, B, C, A1, A2, ...{
    Implementation A() { ... return this; }
    Implementation A1() { ... return this; }
    ...
}

public interface MyClass {
    A A();
    B B();    
    C C();
}

public interface A {
    A1 A1();
    A2 A2();
}

public interface B {
    B1 B1();
}

public interface C {
    C1 C1();
}

...
```